# Symfony2 error 500 instead of 404 in test environment

Tags: php, symfony, jenkins, behat, error-code

I have a Behat test of a given controller action, here is the code (Symfony2.5)

```
public function sendContactFormAction(Request $request, TrainingCenter $trainingCenter)
{
    if (!$trainingCenter->isInstituteProfileVisible()) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(sprintf('The center "%s" (%d) is not visble.', $trainingCenter->getName(), $trainingCenter->getId()));
    }

    if (!$trainingCenter->canBeContactedFromProfile()) {
        throw new AccessDeniedHttpException(sprintf('The center "%s" (%d) can\'t be contacted by email.', $trainingCenter->getName(), $trainingCenter->getId()));
    }
```

It works well in our development workstations but on our integration platform (Jenkins), those `throws` statements raise 500 exceptions instead of 404 or 403, I can't find why.

Comment: Did you check the logs? Both Symfony and web server / php ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it fact it was due to a notice generated by the jmsserializer bundle in the MetaClass deserialise function. After clearing all the cache and refactored a bit the tests it now works. Thanks.